# (UWP) Found item in GridView.Items, but SelectedItem is null

Tags: c#, xaml, gridview, uwp, selecteditem

I have GridView with ItemsSource of ResourceDictionary with SolidColorBrushes.

I want to select the same SolidColorBrush in this GridView as my object with some color of ColorBase. So, I call "selectItemInGridView" method in "ContentDialogItem.xaml.cs" file.

Item is successfully found and set to "color", but finally nothing happened and SelectedItem is still null. How to repair this?

EDIT: Code below

App.xaml

```
.....
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Colors.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
....
```

Colors.xaml

```
....
<ResourceDictionary x:Key="ColorBase">
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="01" x:Name="darkBlue" Color="#2d5ac1" />        
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="02" x:Name="blue" Color="#02b0e7" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="03" x:Name="cyan" Color="#3dc6ac" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="04" x:Name="green" Color="#0f993f" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="05" x:Name="lightGreen" Color="#54c63d" />
</ResourceDictionary>
....
```

MainPage.xaml

```
....
<ListView Name="ListViewItem" IsItemClickEnabled="True" ItemsSource="{x:Bind Items, Mode=OneTime}" SelectionChanged="ListView_SelectionChanged" ItemClick="ListViewItem_ItemClick">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ColorKey}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
....
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
....
private List<Item> items;
private List<Item> Items {
    get {
        if (items == null) {
            items = new List<Item>();
            items.Add(new Item("01"));
            items.Add(new Item("02"));
            items.Add(new Item("03"));
            items.Add(new Item("04"));
            items.Add(new Item("05"));
        }
        return items;
    }
}

private void ListView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e) {
  ListViewItem.SelectedItem = null;
}

private async void ListViewItem_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e) {
    ContentDialogItem contentDialogItem = new ContentDialogItem((Item)e.ClickedItem);
    ContentDialogResult result = await contentDialogItem.ShowAsync();
}
....
```

ContentDialogItem.xaml

```
....
<GridView Name="ColorBaseGridView" SelectionMode="Single" ItemsSource="{StaticResource ColorBase}">
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
           <Rectangle Width="36" Height="36" Fill="{Binding Value}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
....
```

ContentDialogItem.xaml.cs

```
....
private Item selectedItem;
public ContentDialogItem(Item selectedItem) {
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.selectedItem = selectedItem;
    selectItemInGridView(ColorBaseGridView);
}

private List<KeyValuePair<object, object>> colorBase;
private List<KeyValuePair<object, object>> ColorBase {
    get {
        if (colorBase == null) { colorBase = ((ResourceDictionary)Application.Current.Resources["ColorBase"]).ToList(); }
        return colorBase;
    }
}

private void selectItemInGridView(GridView gridView) {
    object color = gridView.Items.SingleOrDefault(item => ((KeyValuePair<object, object>)item).Key.ToString() == selectedItem.ColorKey);
    gridView.SelectedItem = color;
}
....
```

Item.cs

```
public class Item {
    public string ColorKey { get; set; }
    public Item(string ColorKey) { this.ColorKey = ColorKey; }
}
```

Comment: What would be efficient is, use data binding to `bind` the `SelectedItem` of the `GridView` to a property in a `TwoWay` mode and an `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` and raise that property `OnPropertyChanged`. Now on selection changed you can directly `get` the property instead of getting `GridView.SelectedItem` to change the selected item you just need to change the property and your UI would reflect it

Comment: Are you trying to update the code in the UI thread? Also have you tried setting SelectedIndex property?

Comment: Could you share a [mcve] that can reproduce your issue? The code you've shared seems OK. Without more details, we can't identify your problem.